# While doing copy-elision, the compiler doesn't consider the copy constructor in overload resolution, when the move constructor is deleted. Why?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, copy-elision

I can understand the compiler is doing *copy-elision* in the code below, as the copy and move constructors are not invoked in the so called `copy-initialization` done in `main()`. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c4254a63a89d8c6).

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    S() = default;
    S(const S&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << '\n'; }
    S(S&&) { std::cout << "move ctor" << '\n'; }
};

int main() {
    S s = S(); 
}
```

But I can't understand why the code doesn't compile when I delete the move constructor as below:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    S() = default;
    S(const S&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << '\n'; }
    S(S&&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    S s = S(); 
}
```

I can't find anything in §12.8/32 (N4140) that could disallow the **copy constructor** from being used or elided, in this case. This is the sentence that called my attention in §12.8/32, which seems to indicate that the copy constructor should have been considered in the overload resolution:

> If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the
>   type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an
>   rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly cv-qualified),
>   overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an
>   lvalue.

**Edit**

From one of the comments by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) below, I understand that when the object to be copied is designated by an rvalue, the compiler, according to §12.8/32, doesn't consider the copy-constructor as a candidate for the copy, even though the copy would be elided anyway. That is, the end result would be the construction of the object `s` with the default constructor. Instead, in this situation the Standard mandates (where??) the code to be ill-formed. Unless my understanding of this scheme is completely wrong, that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Overload resolution does not fail when it finds a deleted function. Deleted functions are not *non-existent*, they are in a sense *not deleted*. They're simply *illegal to call* (they can be called, and if you do, that's an error).

Comment: And in any event that quote from 12.8/32 doesn't apply.

Comment: Outside of `return` statements, that paragraph is only applicable, when, among other things, "the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue". `S()` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @T.C. So what you're saying is that when the object to copied is an rvalue the overload resolution will not be done using a two-stage process. Is that correct? If that's the case, how can I force the use of the copy constructor in this example? Is there any work around?

Comment: Don't explicitly delete the move constructor? There's generally no good reason to when you still allows copy.

Comment: But how do I avoid the copy elision?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid copy elision?

Comment: I just want to understand the Standard

Comment: @T.C. See my **Edit** above

Comment: Use a compiler switch to disable copy-elision, you will see that your code is still illegal

Comment: @François-MarieArouet *"I understand that when the object to be copied is designated by an rvalue, the compiler, according to §12.8/32, doesn't consider the copy-constructor as a candidate for the copy, even though the copy would be elided anyway"*, wrong, in your case overload resolution finds a move-constructor first (because it is a better match), so the overload resolution itself succeeds, however, since that move-constructor is deleted, a compiler reports an error. if you didn't provide a move-constructor, then the copy-constructor would be picked by overload resolution

Comment: @François-MarieArouet a deleted constructor is treated as if it was user-declared, and it *does* participate in overload resolution

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki But why do deleted functions have to participate in overload resolution?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet because `=delete` doesn't mean *"this function doesn't exist"*. If you don't want a function to exist -> just don't declare it. That is, `=delete` means that if one tries to use such deleted function, a compiler should raise an error.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks for your helpful and insightful comments.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What's the difference in this case, between a private and a deleted move constructor?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet the class itself and friends thereof would be able to exploit the private move constructor

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Great. I've just forgotten about this possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing specific to do with copy elision or constructors; it is just overload resolution.

If we have a pair of overloads:

```
void f( T&& rv );
void f( const T& lv );
```

then the overload resolution rules say that `f( T{} )` is a better match for `f(T&&)`.

Copy elision can elide a copy or move, but only when the code is well-defined ( even if the compiler chooses not to implement copy elision).  Your code is not well-defined, because it specifies to call a deleted function.

Comment: But why do deleted function have to participate in overload resolution?

Comment: @François-MarieArouet that's just how it is. It seems more flexible in this case: you can choose to either define move constructor as deleted, or omit it in which case it won't exist and the copy constructor will be called.